# Calculation of polynomial $g(x)$ satisfies $x\cdot g(x+1)=(x-3)\cdot g(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If a polynomial $g(x)$ satisfies $x\cdot g(x+1)=(x-3)\cdot g(x)$ for all $x$, and $g(3)=6$, then $g(25)=$?

My try: $x\cdot g(x+1)=(x-3)\cdot g(x)$,

Put $x=3$, we get $g(4)=0$, means $(x-4)$ is a factor of $g(x)$.

Similarly put $x=0$. We get $g(0)=0$, means $x$ is a factor of $g(x)$.

This means $g(x)=x\cdot (x-4)h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is a polynomial.

Then how can I calculate it?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, there is no such polynomial $g$... Indeed, $-\mathbb{N}^*$ are all zeroes, so $g=0$, a contradiction. So the question does not make sense. See Andreas' answer.

Comment: No such polynomial in characteristic $0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A repeated use of $g(x+1)=\dfrac{x-3}x g(x)$ gives

$$\begin{array} gg(25)&=&\dfrac{21}{24} g(24)\\ &=&\dfrac{22}{24}\dfrac{21}{23} g(23)\\&=&\cdots \\ &=&\dfrac{21}{24}\dfrac{20}{23}\cdots \frac{1}{4} g(3)\end{array}$$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff So it appears that there is no polynomial $g$ that satisfies the conditions. You might want to edit your answer.

Comment: @julien Yes, I can see that. What do you suggest?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff It's totally up to you. Maybe you could prove that there is no such $g$ in characteristic $0$.

Answer (score 4):

We are talking polynomials with integer coefficients, right? Let us follow the suggestion of  @IshanBanerjee

We have seen that $0$ is a root of $g$. Plug $-1$ for $x$ in
$$
x\cdot g(x+1)=(x-3)\cdot g(x)
$$
to find $-1$ is also a root. Plug $-2$ to see $-2$ is also a root...

Comment: Integer, real, complex coefficients... There is no such $g$. No?

Comment: If you exclude $g = 0$, yes. I do not have the time now to look at the positive characteristic case, except to note that in characteristic $3$ things like $g = x^{3^{k}} - x$ appear to work.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was assuming characteristic $0$.